# Exclude certain value in order by and duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with countries, e.g.:

> - Holland
> - Germany
> - Italy
> - Belgium
> - France

I'd like to order this list alphabetically, but put one country on top, e.g. Holland. I can achieve this with:

> SELECT Country FROM Countries ORDER BY Country = 'Holland' DESC, Country

However, I would also like to include Holland within the alphabetical list, as a duplicate. The list should look like:

> - Holland
> - Belgium
> - France
> - Germany
> - Holland
> - Italy

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to duplicate the row is to use a UNION.

```
SELECT Country
FROM (SELECT 1 AS priority, Country
      FROM Countries
      WHERE Country = "Holland"
      UNION
      SELECT 2 AS priority, Country
      FROM Countries) AS subquery
ORDER BY priority, Country
```

Comment: This is indeed the way to go - you must have some sort of priority, either in the table or in the query as @Baramar shows here. In fact, his is a really common approach, for a lot of times you might not have priority in your DB table and it might be impossible to add. Wrapping it in a second query ensures you would get the right ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UNION to append that value to the top of your query results:

```
SELECT 'Holland' 
UNION ALL
SELECT Country FROM Countries ORDER BY Country ASC
```

Comment: and if *Holland* is not in the country list?

Comment: @juergend a valid question, even if it seems silly. A slightly better example would be "What if Holland changes its name". OK, might not be _really_ better but in general, you can expect the elements in your database to change more often than be deleted. So what if, instead, you were selecting, say, PC parts names and wanted to give priority to one - then what if that changes the name for whatever reason. Or what if it gets removed, indeed. You are much better selecting by PK rather than appending the string.